# Zend 2 redirect with toRoute not working

Tags: php, redirect, controller, routes, zend-framework2

Why is Zend 2 such a `!@#(#(!#@??`

OK, so I'm trying to get a simple redirect working. I have a controller called 'listitems' with an action called 'editlistitem'. After hours of banging on it with a hand sledge, I've finally got the form to work and the validation to work and the hydration to Doctrine to work so I can save the result.

The last step is to redirect the user to the 'showlistitem' action which includes the id trailing it. (full route sub path is 'listitem/showlistitem/2' where 2 is the id I want to see)

I have tried:

```
$this->redirect()->toRoute('/listitem/showlistitem/2');
$this->redirect()->toRoute('listitem/showlistitem/2');
$this->redirect()->toRoute('showlistitem/2');
$this->redirect()->toRoute('listitem/showlistitem', array('id' => 2));
$this->redirect()->toRoute('listitem-showlistitem', array('id' => 2));
```

None of them flippin work! (they all return route not found)

A route to the controller is in modules.config.php with a child route to the action. I can go directly to the url by typing it in manually and it works fine. How in the *bleep* do I get Zend to redirect the user to that route from an action?

Comment: 2nd to last one looks like the right syntax. Can you add your routing config to the question if it's not working?

Comment: If you really want to redirect to url then use _$this->redirect()->toUrl('/listitem/showlistitem/2');_. Otherwise use @blackbishop's answer.

Comment: It is a `!@#(#(!#@??`

Answer (score 3):

The `toRoute` method provided by the [The Redirect plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-redirect) needs the `route name` to be passed as parameter. This is its desciption :

> **toRoute**(string $route = null, array $params = array(), array $options = array(), boolean $reuseMatchedParams = false)
>
> Redirects to a named route, using the provided `$params` and `$options` to assembled the URL.

Given this simple route configuration example :

```
//module.config.php

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),  
        'app' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/app',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller'    => 'index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'id'=>'[0-9]+',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

This redirection works :

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('app/default', 
           array('controller'=>'controller-name', 'action'=>'action-name', 'id'=>$id));
```

In your case, this would work :

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('app/default', 
            array('controller'=>'listitem', 'action'=>'showlistitem', 'id'=>2));
```

Comment: You save my day